# MsBuild Cpp BeforeBuild not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

I want to execute a `target` before project builds.

I have define the following in the .vcxproj file.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
   <Message Text="BeforeBuilds" />
   <CallTarget Targets="myTarget" />
  </Target>

<Import Project="..\GetCat.targets" />
 <Target Name="DefaultBeforeTarget" BeforeTargets="Default">
  <CallTarget Targets="myTarget" />
 </Target>

<Target Name="myTarget" Inputs="$(TargetPath)"  Outputs="$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).tlb" DependsOnTargets="GetCat">
<Message Text="Calling myTarget" />
<Exec Command="mkdri HelloW" />
</Target>
```

The `myTarget` `<Message>` is not getting called.

How to fix this?

Comment: Your question title is about BeforeCompile, but your code uses BeforeBuild. Please clarify what you want to do, and also provide a minimal working sample to reproduce the issue (e.g. we don't know what GetCat.targets contains, or what GetCat does, but that might not even be relevant to the question)

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727351/what-happened-to-beforebuild-and-other-targets-in-vs2012